# Trying to us an Azure CLI command in a do loop failing(works outside of loop)

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm trying to use some Azure cli commands in a do loop.
The commands work outside of the loop.
I can't figure out why they return null outside of the loop.

```
    `az login --service-principal **creds removed**
     displayName=$(az ad app list --all | jq '. [] .displayName')
     for name in $displayName;
     do
         echo $name  
         az ad app list --all --display-name $name | jq ".[0] .passwordCredentials[0].endDate" 
     done`
```

For example one of the display names is boss-app if i do the following

```
az ad app list --all --display-name "boss-app" | jq ".[0] .passwordCredentials[0].endDate"
"2228-02-34T25:50:41.324437+00:00
```

Even if I put the full command in the loop it outputs the date correctly it just seems when i try and use the variable $name it doesn't work.

Apologies if this is a bit of a noob question.

Comment: Are there spaces in any of the display names?

Comment: No, they start and end with the quotes.

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Charles, 
I did try to post but it was deleted.
When assigning the Display name as the name value it also took the quotes around the json.
Removing the quotes around this and running the same command resolved the issue. 
It did confuse me somewhat as running the command with the name value in quotes directly to a shell worked.
Also im not sure why the command processed and did not throw an error if it was not seeing the display name value.
Thanks for your assistance with this issue.

Comment: There are also other ways to solve the problem. The key is that you need to know how does the shell defines a list variable. That's the problem. My answer just shows you one way. If you want to know other ways, please add the comments below my answer, and then we can communicate in the chatting room. And if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Charles, I've tried your solution and it doesn't change the output of the script at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the script into this:

```
az login --service-principal **creds removed**
for name in $(az ad app list --all | jq '. [] .displayName')
do
    echo $name  
    az ad app list --all --display-name $name | jq ".[0] .passwordCredentials[0].endDate" 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have filtered the ad app with `--display-name` in the loop, I think you should change the code in the loop like this without specfiying the array index`[0]`:

```
   az login --service-principal **creds removed**
     displayName=$(az ad app list --all | jq '. [] .displayName')
     for name in $displayName;
     do
         echo $name  
         az ad app list --all --display-name $name | jq ".[] .passwordCredentials[].endDate" 
     done
```

Result

[image]

Command

[image]

In addition, If you want to use Azure CLI global parameter `--query` instead of `jq`, you could use it as below:

Note that, try to use double quotes `""` for Windows, use single quotes `''` for Linux OS in the query.

```
az login --service-principal **creds removed**
displayName=$(az ad app list --all --query "[].displayName" -o tsv)
     for name in $displayName;
     do
         echo $name
         az ad app list --all --display-name $name --query "[].passwordCredentials[].endDate"
     done
```

Comment: This did not product the expected result it printed out the name display names but nothing more.

Comment: Where do you run the Azure CLI?